# Where are the acpiphp and pci_hotplug kernel modules for KVM hotplug in CentOS/RHEL?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

On the [this how-to](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Hotadd_pci_devices) I read the following:

> I loaded the following modules to get pci hotplug working:
>
> - acpiphp
> - pci_hotplug
>
> You can either add these to your distro's module list to load on boot,
>   or run a command like this.
>
> ```
> for m in acpiphp pci_hotplug; do sudo modprobe ${m}; done
> ```

However, on CentOS 6.3 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.3 this modules does not exist, on Ubuntu Server and Debian 6 it does.

Why? Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, it's already built into your kernel (rather than a module). Have you actually tried hotplugging devices?

I don't have access to a CentOS/RHEL machine now, but on Fedora, I see the kernel configuration contains this:

```
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI=y
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_ACPI=y
```

While on Ubuntu 12.04, I see this:

```
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI=y
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_ACPI=m
```

Comment: CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI=y
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_FAKE=m
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_ACPI=y
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_ACPI_IBM=m
# CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_CPCI is not set
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_SHPC=m

Comment: @GiovanniBennelli So, my thoughts are valid, right? Again: Have you actually tried hotplugging devices?

Comment: ok, PCI hotplug support, in the guest, work fine.